# How to add Custom Block between `product.info.media` and `product.info.details` on Product page in Magento 2.3.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Here is my code of `catalog_product_view.xml` -

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <container after="product.info.media" name='custom-pro-review-section' htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom_pro_review_section">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="second.product.info.review" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/review.phtml" />
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" after="second.product.info.review" name="product-extra" template="product/view/product-extra.phtml"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

and Block is coming between `product.info.media` and `product.info.details` section but showing on top of page.

**Actual Result (see image)-**

[image]

**Expected Result will be as -**

[image]

Please help..... Thanks

Comment: your custom block move after add to cart section

Comment: have you checked the css of the other elements?! maybe your markup is on the right positions but css might be changing how they are displayed

Comment: I didn't add any CSS to the custom block (product information text). this is the single <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code , may be this solved your problem .

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block before="product.info.details" class="Vendor\Extension\Block\File" name="blockname" template="Vendor_Extension::customfile.phtml"/>        
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Bro `product.info.main` is different block. and `product.info.details` block is outside of it. so how's it possible.

Comment: oh sorry i have updated by answer you can try above code